# Existe diferença ao juntar dois arrays com array_merge ou com "+"?

Tags: php, array

Eu costumava unir dois *arrays*, em PHP, usando a função `array_merge`:

```
$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

No entanto, mais recentemente passei a ver uniões de *arrays* com `+` (sinal de soma):

```
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

Existe alguma diferença entre esses os dois métodos?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters valeu pelo toque, quando eu havia escrito o título esse post não apareceu. No entanto, a resposta é boa, então vou validá-la assim mesmo. :)

Comment: Rodrigo, sem problemas. É melhor porque as perguntas fazem referência uma a outra. No caso, você usou o operador "+" no título, e eu coloquei "soma".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Existem duas diferenças entre [+](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) e o [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php):

Operador [+](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

Quando usamos este operador no caso de termos elementos com as mesmas chaves (sejam elas numéricas ou não) os valores do array da esquerda prevalecem  sobre os do array da direita. Considere o exemplo:

```
$a = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", 'lol');
$b = array("a" => "pear", "b" => "strawberry", "c" => "cherry", 'lil');

$merged = $a + $b;
```

Resultado:

```
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [0] => lol
    [c] => cherry
)
```

Como se pode ver, em elementos com a mesma chave em ambos os arrays (`$a` e `$b`), só os de `$a` foram considerados, ignorando os elementos em `$b`.

Com [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php):

Aqui é o oposto, no caso de termos chaves iguais (não numéricas) as do array da direita  prevalecem sobre as do da esquerda. No caso de termos chaves numéricas, e serem as mesmas chaves em ambos os arrays elas são redefinidas de maneira a que ambos os elementos sejam incluidos na fusão:

```
$a = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", 'lol');
$b = array("a" => "pear", "b" => "strawberry", "c" => "cherry", 'lil');

$merged = array_merge($a, $b);
```

Resultado:

```
(
    [a] => pear
    [b] => strawberry
    [0] => lol
    [c] => cherry
    [1] => lil
)
```